# Explaining the explain results of H2 database

Tags: h2, ignite

Running Apache Ignite 1.30 which uses H2 as the indexing system.

I ran my query through explain and got.

```
{"result":"[[
SELECT\n
    FIELD1 AS __C0\n
    FROM \"cache\".TRX\n

    /* \"cache\".\"FIELD2_idx\": FIELD2 = ?1 */\n

    WHERE FIELD2 = ?1], [SELECT\n
    __C0 AS FIELD1\n
    FROM \"cache\".__Z0()\n

    /* function */]]"}
```

Ok so I know it's using field2 as the index, but what is the second select?

Comment: With "the second select", do you mean the `SELECT __C0 AS FIELD1 FROM "cache".__Z0()`? It is a function call (to __Z0), it can not use an index.

Comment: Yes, so does this mean that ignite can't use the H2 index?

Comment: Function calls can not have an index. So, which index do you want to use?

Comment: My query is select Field1 from TRX where Field2 = ? so thats fine it seems to be picking the right index, but what is the second select?

Comment: Function calls can not have an index.

Comment: Which index do you want to use for the second select?

Comment: Actually it got resolved on the ignite site finally. http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Explain-the-h2-explain-td1344.html

Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first SELECT here is the execution plan for the query that is executed on remote nodes, the second one is for the local query executed during the reduce step.

Remote query execution plan shows that the index is correctly used and the query will be executed in the fastest possible way.

Since there are no aggregations in this particular query, the reduce step is trivial - result sets from remote nodes are simply merged into one. So execution plan actually doesn't show any useful information in this case.